# How to we insert the value between the <option> and </option> into phpmyadmin database, instead of option value?

Tags: php, html, css, embed

I have created a dropdown list with links in the options, but while I'm submitting the form, the link goes into the database, instead of the value inside the option tags.

```
<select name="loc" id="location" onchange="setIframeSource()"> 
  <li>TV</li>
     <option value = "" disabled selected>Select Channel</option>
     <option name="News" Value="News"><p>News</p></option>
     <option name="ABC News" value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/w_Ma8oQLmSM">ABC News</option> 
     <option name="RT" value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NvCSr7qzAAM?rel=0&showinfo=0&modestbranding=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="">RT</option> 
     <option name="Bloomberg Live" value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dp8PhLsUcFE?rel=0&modestbranding=1">Bloomberg Live</option> 
     <option name="Skynews" value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/x5EZPXBuh7g">Sky News</option> 
    
  </select>
```

My question here is, instead of passing the link to the database, I wanted the name of the channel, say ABC news inside the database?

Comment: <option name="ABC News" value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/w_Ma8oQLmSM">ABC News</option>  chnage this to <option name="ABC News" value="ABC News>ABC News</option>

Comment: The `value` attribute is what's being submitted. You have two options, one is to make the value what you want (as Sanjit suggests) or completely omitting the attribute (then the label is submitted). I'd suggest the first approach - it makes for a clearer intention.

Comment: Side note: options don't need names. Only the `select` tag.

Comment: But on clicking ABC news, I need to play it? @SanjitBhardwaj

Answer (score 0):

I dont konw if you will need option value also.
but if you want only option name value then you can do this with jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#location').on('change', function() {
        var selectedOption = $(this).find(':selected').attr('name');
        setIframeSource();
    });
</script>

<select name="loc" id="location"> 
  <li>TV</li>
     <option value = "" disabled selected>Select Channel</option>
     <option name="News" Value="News"><p>News</p></option>
     <option name="ABC News" value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/w_Ma8oQLmSM">ABC News</option> 
     <option name="RT" value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NvCSr7qzAAM?rel=0&showinfo=0&modestbranding=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="">RT</option> 
     <option name="Bloomberg Live" value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dp8PhLsUcFE?rel=0&modestbranding=1">Bloomberg Live</option> 
     <option name="Skynews" value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/x5EZPXBuh7g">Sky News</option> 
    
  </select>
```

and then sent selectedOption variable with ajax.

Comment: Thanks a lot... But could you help me in Php?

Comment: Or if you dont want to use ajax you can add an hidden input and when the select change, you will take the name of selected option and assign it to the value of hidden input and receive it in php file after submitting form